# Is SimpleCursorAdapter constructor supposed to observe column order in constructor?

Tags: android, sqlite, listview, simplecursoradapter

I am testing a basic SQLite query and using a SimpleCursorAdapter to populate a ListView containing LinearLayout's that contain TextViews of the column data, but when I change the order of the TextView's, the data in the TextView's move with the order, not with the R.id.

In the example below, the order of the TextView's is @+id/rowid and @+id/name, and the data from the cursor correctly populates.

However if I modify the row.xml to change the order of the EditText's (I cut the entire TextView element and paste it on the opposite side of the other TextView), the data from the cursor stays in the same order, ie. the DatabaseHelper.NAME data from the cursor goes into the @+id/rowid EditText, and the _id data from the cursor goes into @+id/name

Is this normal behaviour? I expected the SimpleCursorAdapter 'from' columns to populate the 'to' views in their respective order in the constructor.

Example code:

```
    Cursor usersCursor;
    String query = String.format("SELECT _id, %s FROM %s",
            DatabaseHelper.NAME, DatabaseHelper.TABLE);
    cursor = db.getReadableDatabase().rawQuery(query, null);

    usersCursorAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(getActivity(),
            R.layout.row, usersCursor,
            new String[] { "_id", DatabaseHelper.NAME }, 
            new int[] { R.id.rowid, R.id.name },
            0);

    userList.setAdapter(usersCursorAdapter);
```

and the R.layout.row.xml is:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/LinearLayout1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <TextView
      android:id="@+id/rowid"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
      android:layout_marginRight="16dp" />

    <TextView
      android:id="@+id/name"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_margin="4dp"
      android:textSize="36sp" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The views that should display column in the "from" parameter. These should all be TextViews. The first N views in this list are given the values of the first N columns in the from parameter.

[Source](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/SimpleCursorAdapter.html#SimpleCursorAdapter(android.content.Context,%20int,%20android.database.Cursor,%20java.lang.String[],%20int[],%20int))

Try cleaning your project and running it again.

My guess is that the `R.id` values in your `R.java` file don't match the ones in the compiled Java code. This is entirely possible if you only changed the XML files. `R.java` will be regenerated, but the classes which use `R.id` are not recompiled with the new values. Since `R.id` contains `final` constants, the compiler can optimize the byte code by using the constant value directly rather than loading it from a variable. This directly causes the problem you are seeing when `R.java` changes but the rest of your code is not recompiled.

Comment: Darn, that did it. So would this be an Eclipse/ADT-specific thing, or is it related to the SDK build tools?

Comment: @troutit It's possible to see this behavior with any build tool that is unaware that your Java code depends on `R.java`. If the build tool doesn't know to rebuild your code when `R.java` changes, you will see these kinds of problems.